# Trigger on ComboBox SelectedValue not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a `TextBox` that I want to change `Width` based on a `ComboBox.SelectedValue`.

This is my code:

```xml
<ComboBox Name="cmbService"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedValue="IsCustomAvailable" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataServer}">
</ComboBox>
```

When selected item changes, I can see that `SelectedValue` has some value and works well but it doesn't work in trigger:

```xml
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="400" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=cmbService}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="280" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `SelectedValue` property of your `ComboBox` in this way, you should use the `SelectedValuePath` to specify that you wish to use the `IsCustomAvailable` property.

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbService"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataServer}"
          SelectedValuePath="IsCustomAvailable"/>
```

You should also replace the `SelectedValue="IsCustomAvailable"` markup with `SelectedValue="true"` or remove it to keep type consistent with `bool`.